# Discord.py - Cooldown Timer on Repeated Bot Activity

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am programming a bot that pings a specific role in my channel when a specific keyword is found in an embedded message, however I want there to be a cooldown on when this can be used. For instance, this keyword might come up 4 times in the span of 5 minutes and I only want it to ping once (at the first case) instead of 4 individual times.

This issue is that there are multiple keywords that I am scraping for, and I want the cooldown to only apply to repeated keywords because say my keywords are "apple" and "banana", I still want the bot to ping for each individual one even if they are within the cooldown range. But if "apple" were to appear repeated times within that cooldown range, I only want one ping for that keyword if this is making any sense.

Below I've posted the code that I have for this section without the cooldown applied. I've tried looking throughout the internet and it is still making very little sense to me at least in this application so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
keyword_match = keyword_check(total_text)
if(keyword_match[0]):
  await message.channel.send("role_id")
```

Comment: you could use directory to keep word and when it was pinged - `data = {"apple": time_of_last_ping}`  and then you can compare it with current time and skip `ping` when `time_of_last_ping - current_time  < 5minutes`

Comment: @furas would I need to use datetime for this?

Comment: you need `datetime` or `time.time()` (and work with seconds ie. `5minutes = 5*60 seconds`)